# JavaScript - Get users local time without UTC offset

Tags: javascript, date-fns

When my local time is 8am and I do this:

`JSON.stringify(new Date())`

I get **"2019-06-17T14:00:01.003Z"**. I believe the underlying implementation of stringify a new date is `.toISOString()`. So it adds 6 hours to my time to include the timezone offset.

Fair enough.

Now I want my DateTime string to not add this 6 hours. I want the current client's local time without being relative to UTC time.

E.g. I'd like to see this:

**"2019-06-17T08:00:01"** - Not sure if I need the Z at the end.

I'll be sending this date/time string to a C# Web Api which will treat it as a DateTime.

How do I do this?
I am running **date-fns** if it makes it any easier.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55108480/794234) on another question discussing how date's are stored in js.  What you want is called an "epoch shift" there's sample code for doing it at the end of that answer.

Comment: this may work `new Date().toLocaleString()`

Comment: I know it might be an overkill but moment.js might be a solution and you might not want to perform manually tasks on datetimes due to reasons mentioned by @just.another.programmer